# How can I update using jQuery and NOT from a file the contents of a div?

Tags: jquery

how can I reload the contents of a div not by using the `.load('file')` ? Just the contents of it (they are dynamically updated upon refresh).

```
<div id="myreload">
.
.
.
</div>
```

This is a code I used to use

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function() {
    var SANAjax = function(){
        $('#details').empty().addClass('loading')
          .load('home.php', function() {
             $(this).removeClass('loading') 
          });
    }
    setInterval(SANAjax, 5000 );
});

</script>
```

Thank you all.

Comment: I'm not quiet sure what you are asking, do you want to load it with the contents of another page?

Comment: It sounds like you have a `div` that has different data every time the page is loaded, and you want to reload only the contents of the div to contain what it *would* contain if you were to refresh the page... except you don't want the page to refresh. Is this close?

Comment: Yes that's right. But I want to load php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myreload').html('your contents here');
```